# Как определить, лежит ли один круг внутри другого?

Tags: геометрия

Как определить, лежит ли один многоульник внутри другого?
Есть массив трехмерных вершин двух многоугольников, как определить находится ли один внутри другого?

Comment: Так круг или многоугольник?

Answer (score 4):

> Как определить, лежит ли один круг внутри другого?

если есть 2 круга `(x1, y1, r1)` и `(x2, y2, r2)` и `r1 > r2`, то чтобы определить лежит ли второй круг целиком внутри первого нужно чтобы выполнялось условие

```
sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2) + r2 <= r1
```

т.е. расстояние от центра большого круга до малого + радиус малого круга не должны превышать радиус большого круга

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]